# How can my 2nd constructor parameter work?

Tags: java

```
       import java.util.Scanner;
       class BloodData{
            static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            static String bloodType;
            static String rhFactor;
 
         public BloodData(){
            bloodType = "O";
            rhFactor = "+";
       }
         public BloodData(String bt, String rh){
           bloodType = bt;
           rhFactor = rh;
       }
         public void display() {
           System.out.println(bloodType+rhFactor+" is added to the blood bank");
       }

         public static void main(String[]args) {

           System.out.println("Enter Blood Type(O, A, B, AB)");
           System.out.println("Enter rhFactor('+' or '-')");
           BloodData bd= new 
           BloodData(BloodData.bloodType=in.nextLine(),BloodData.rhFactor=in.nextLine());

           BloodData bd1= new BloodData();
           bd.display();

        }
      }
```

How can i use the constructor with 2 String parameters? because when I always run the code the first one only run. I'm only a beginner so hope someone could help because I already watched a lot of Youtube vids and I really didn't know why this happens

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding what `static` means

Comment: And also how arguments are passed to methods and constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't use named parameters like this for method or constructors. I would be surprised if a video showed such syntax...

```
new BloodData(BloodData.bloodType=in.nextLine(),BloodData.rhFactor=in.nextLine())
```

You need to define String variables on the line above, then pass them into the constructor. You also shouldn't be combining instance constructors with static variables

```
   class BloodData{
        private String bloodType;
        private String rhFactor;

        public BloodData(String type, String rhFactor) {
            this.bloodType = type;
            this.rhFactor = rhFactor;
        }
   ...

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String x = in.nextLine();
            String y = in.nextLine();
            BloodData bd = new BloodData(x, y);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call a constructor having two parameters: Use this

```
BloodData blooddata = new BloodData("A","+");
```

Comment: He/she did... Under `"Enter rhFactor"`